# Simple form, mongoid, has_one not saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I have mongoid has_one relationship

```
class Banner
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :url, type: String
   has_one :asset
   embedded_in :campaign

   validates_presence_of :url
end
```

And

```
class Asset
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :user
```

I am using simple_form with nested form using cocoon.

definition for simple_form

```
<%= f.input :asset,  :collection => @assets%>
<%= f.input :url %>
```

This is output from post action:

```
campaign[banners_attributes][0][url]:Gadf
campaign[banners_attributes][0][asset]:506203a70fc16ce14f00000d
campaign[banners_attributes][0][_destroy]:
campaign[banners_attributes][0][id]:5062f1330fc16cfd6b000011
```

But asset is never associated for this banner. Any ideas?

Comment: So the Mongo document ID for the asset record ```506203a70fc16ce14f00000d``` is getting posted by the controller action, but it never gets saved to the Banner?

Answer (score 1):

try `has_one :asset, autosave: true`